# UITextField move up when keyboard appears in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, keyboard-events

I use this code for move the view up when keyboard appears, in my login page this code worked great, but in the signup page it did not work.

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    animateViewMoving(true, moveValue: 100)
}
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    animateViewMoving(false, moveValue: 100)
}

func animateViewMoving (up:Bool, moveValue :CGFloat){
    var movementDuration:NSTimeInterval = 0.3
    var movement:CGFloat = ( up ? -moveValue : moveValue)
    UIView.beginAnimations( "animateView", context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState(true)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(movementDuration )
    self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0,  movement)
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}
```

I have another function to return key on the keyboard, it also worked on the login page but not on the signup page. All things are same between the two pages.

```
  func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

Comment: check that your delegete is connected or not

Comment: for demo check this link : https://github.com/harshilkotecha/UIScrollViewWhenKeyboardAppearInSwift3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

have you assigned your delegate of UITextField in your ViewController class?
if not set it to self.

```
self.youttextfield.delegate = self
```

Comment: @Mohammad is it solved your problem? please mention, so we can suggest you more solutions.

Comment: thanks for helping @Israr, you are right but i use this code without 'UITextFieldDelegate' in my login page and worked great,

Answer (score 0):

Demo link : https://github.com/harshilkotecha/UIScrollViewWhenKeyboardAppearInSwift3

when you have multiple textview it is so difficult so best solution ->

step 1 : add UITextFieldDelegate

```
class ScrollViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {
```

step 2 :create new IBOutlet but don't connect with any text field

```
//  get current text box when user Begin editing
    @IBOutlet weak var activeTextField: UITextField?
```

step 3 : write this two method when user focus on text filed object pass the reference and store in activeTextField

```
// get current text field
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField)
    {
        activeTextField=textField;
    }
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField)
    {
        activeTextField=nil;
    }
```

step 5 : set Notification in viewdidload setNotificationKeyboard

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            // call method for keyboard notification
            self.setNotificationKeyboard()
        }

        // Notification when keyboard show
        func setNotificationKeyboard ()  {
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWasShown(notification:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillBeHidden(notification:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
        }
```

step 6 : two method for hide and unhide

```
func keyboardWasShown(notification: NSNotification)
    {
        var info = notification.userInfo!
        let keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.size
        let contentInsets : UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardSize!.height+10, 0.0)
        self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
        self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
        var aRect : CGRect = self.view.frame
        aRect.size.height -= keyboardSize!.height
        if let activeField = self.activeTextField
        {
            if (!aRect.contains(activeField.frame.origin))
            {
                self.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(activeField.frame, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
// when keyboard hide reduce height of scroll view


 func keyboardWillBeHidden(notification: NSNotification){
        let contentInsets : UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0,0.0, 0.0)
        self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
        self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
```