# UIScrollView scroll up on Keyboard

Tags: ios, ipad, uiscrollview, keyboard, uitextview

**Problem Statement** : I have Nib file of UIView contains UIScrollview, In scrollview I have several TextFields and a TextView at the Bottom. What I want is to scroll upward when textfield or Textview starts editing.

What I tried :

In custome Method

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWasShown(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
```

I am calling this method parent view.

Notification Handling:

```
func keyboardWasShown(notification: NSNotification)
{
    var userInfo = notification.userInfo!
    var keyboardFrame:CGRect = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    keyboardFrame = self.convert(keyboardFrame, from: nil)

    var contentInset:UIEdgeInsets = self.mainScroll.contentInset
    contentInset.bottom = keyboardFrame.size.height
    self.mainScroll.contentInset = contentInset
}
```

This is working perfectly for UITextFields, But not working UITextView. Any idea where is the mistake.

PS: I have set the Delegates of UITextField and UITextView as well.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: you can use contentoffset for scroll the  scrollview.

Comment: Use the https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager, which automatically detect the textField or textView and accordingly manage all the keyboard handling.

Comment: @ZahidShabbir : The scrollview is not scrolling up or scrolling a little in case of textview?

Comment: @Poles It didn't scroll. But it did scroll in case of UITextField

Comment: @zahidshabbir : Have you tried using _contentOffset_ ?

Comment: @zahidshabbir Please look at below answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITextField move up when keyboard appears in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33274780/uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-appears-in-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace keyboardWasShown function with the below function :

```
 func keyboardWasShown(notification: NSNotification)
{
    var userInfo = notification.userInfo!
    var keyboardFrame:CGRect = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    keyboardFrame = self.convert(keyboardFrame, from: nil)
    self.mainScroll.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: keyboardFrame.size.height - Any number that fits your need.)
}
```

In keyBoardWillHide :

```
self.mainScroll.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
```

Hope it will help. 
Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

Demo link : https://github.com/harshilkotecha/UIScrollViewWhenKeyboardAppearInSwift3

when you have multiple textview it is so difficult so best solution ->

step 1 : add  **UITextFieldDelegate**

```
class ScrollViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {
```

step 2 :create new IBOutlet but don't connect with any text field

```
//  get current text box when user Begin editing
    @IBOutlet weak var activeTextField: UITextField?
```

step 3 : write this two method when user focus on text filed object pass the reference and store in activeTextField

```
// get current text field
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField)
    {
        activeTextField=textField;
    }
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField)
    {
        activeTextField=nil;
    }
```

step 5 : set Notification in viewdidload **setNotificationKeyboard**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        // call method for keyboard notification
        self.setNotificationKeyboard()
    }

    // Notification when keyboard show
    func setNotificationKeyboard ()  {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWasShown(notification:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillBeHidden(notification:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }
```

step 6 : two methods for hide and show keyboard

```
func keyboardWasShown(notification: NSNotification)
    {
        var info = notification.userInfo!
        let keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.size
        let contentInsets : UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardSize!.height+10, 0.0)
        self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
        self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
        var aRect : CGRect = self.view.frame
        aRect.size.height -= keyboardSize!.height
        if let activeField = self.activeTextField
        {
            if (!aRect.contains(activeField.frame.origin))
            {
                self.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(activeField.frame, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
    // when keyboard hide reduce height of scroll view
    func keyboardWillBeHidden(notification: NSNotification){
        let contentInsets : UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0,0.0, 0.0)
        self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
        self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardNotification), name: UIResponder.keyboardDidChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)


@objc func keyboardNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
        if let userInfo = (notification as NSNotification).userInfo {
            let endFrame = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue
            let duration:TimeInterval = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber)?.doubleValue ?? 0
            let animationCurveRawNSN = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber
            let animationCurveRaw = animationCurveRawNSN?.uintValue ?? UIView.AnimationOptions().rawValue
            let animationCurve:UIView.AnimationOptions = UIView.AnimationOptions(rawValue: animationCurveRaw)
            if (endFrame?.origin.y)! >= UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height {
                scrollViewBottomConstraint?.constant = 0
            } else {
                if tabBarController?.tabBar.frame == nil {
                    return
                }
                scrollViewBottomConstraint?.constant = endFrame!.size.height - (tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.height)!
                let bottomOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
                scrollView.setContentOffset(bottomOffset, animated: true)
            }
            UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, options: animationCurve, animations: { self.view.layoutIfNeeded() }, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

usage:

```
1.connect the scrollView outlet to your controller and set its name to 'scrollView'
2.connect the scrollView bottom constraint to your controller & set its name to 'scrollViewBottomConstraint'
3.put the notification observer to your ViewDidLoad function.
```